# Could the likelihood increase monotonically in a misspecified EM algorithm?

Tags: markov-process, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I am dealing with the estimation of a Gaussian Hidden Markov Model with conditional distribution given the first-order Markov state $S_t = j,\ j=1,...,J$
$$
Y_t|S_t=j\sim N(0,\sigma^2_j)
$$
where the variance has the following non-standard specification
$$
\sigma^2_j = \mathbb{1}_{(S_t=1)}+\mathbb{1}_{(S_t>1)}*(S_t-1)*c
$$
with $\mathbb{1}_{(A)}$ being the indicator function of the event A.

I derived an EM algorithm to estimate, among the standard parameters of the HMM, $\sigma^2$ and $c$. The algorithm delivers a monotonic increasing likelihood but it does not seem to be able to identify the true model under simulation. I am therefore wondering, could the likelihood still increase monotonically if my algorithm was ill-derived and/or implemented?

Comment: By construction, EM steps see an increase in the observed likelihood, whether or not the model is misspecified. I do not understand what you mean by "identify the true model" and by an "ill-derived" algorithm.

Comment: With identify the true model I mean that the EM could not deliver the true values for $\sigma^2$ and $c$. By ill-derived I mean that wrong expressions for the Q-step might be provided to the algorithm.

Comment: 1. EM delivers the maximum likelihood estimator of the true parameters not the true parameters.

Comment: 2. If there is an error in the code or in the $Q$-step, anything can happen. Hence observing monotonicity is not a sufficient proof that the code and the $Q$-function are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the transition probabilities $p(S_t|S_{t-1})$ in your HMM, so I will assume that your observations are i.i.d.. If that is the case, no implementation of the EM algorithm will be able to converge to the ground-truth parameters, since what we have here is a tell-tale example of non identifiability.

The distribution of $Y_t$ is a mixture of Gaussian distributions having all the same mean $\mu = 0$ but different variances $\{\sigma^2_j\}_j$: hence, $Y_t$ also follows a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 0$. Such a distribution can be perfectly and uniquely described by its mean and variance (2 free parameters). Here, you are trying to fit much more free parameters: many different combinations of parameters will equally well explain the data. The algorithm won't be able to discriminate between them, and hence to converge to the ground-truth values.

We describe a similar problem in Figures 2 and 3 of the following paper:

[Gontier, C., & Pfister, J. P. (2020). Identifiability of a binomial synapse. Frontiers in computational neuroscience, 14, 558477.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2020.558477/full)

The issue is thus not in your implementation of the EM, but in the model itself.

Comment: The $S_t$ are first-order Markov, otherwise it would not be a Hidden Markov model. They come with the usual transition matrix $\Gamma$, whose estimation is however independent of the shape of the Gaussian parameters.

Comment: I do not agree with the sentence: "The distribution of  is a mixture of Gaussian distributions having all the same mean =0 but different variances {2}: hence,  also follows a normal distribution with mean =0." Simply plotting the density of the mixture shows a Mexican-hat shape that differs from a Normal density.